# PHP explode strings in array to multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, recursion, multidimensional-array, explode

I've seen many questions around this topic, but not any near the case I have.

I have like a really simple folder path as key and want to make the array into a multidimensional array.

**My current array**

```
[
  'projects'                  => 'A path',
  'projects/project-a'        => 'Another path',
  'projects/project-b'        => 'Yet another path',
  'about/me/and/someone/else' => 'Path about me'
]
```

**This is the result I try to get:**

```
[
  'projects' => [
    'path'     => 'A path',
    'children' => [
      'project-a' => [
        'path' => 'Another path'
      ],
      'project-b' => [
        'path' => 'Yet another path'
      ]
    ]
  ],
  'about' => [
    'children' => [
      'me' => [
        'children' => [
          'and' => [
            'children' => [
              'someone' => [
                'children' => [
                  'else' => [
                    'path' => 'Path about me'
                  ]
                ]
              ]
            ]
          ]
        ]
      ]
    ]
  ]
]
```

Maybe I can use [array_walk_recursive](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php) somehow. I know [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) can be used to split the parts by `/`.

**Notes**

- `projects/project-a` does not have children.
- `about` and all children except the last one does not have a path.
- The depth of the array is unknown.

Comment: First try yourself, then if you cannot do it ask a question and show what you've tried.

Comment: yes you can use explode with some tweaks. As said by @KIKOSoftware you need to try it by userself

Comment: This is quite trivial to solve. From the top of my head the fastest would be using nested foreach and `explode` traversing the root for each. If you are indexing the internet you might need to hash visited paths and perhaps try to find them O(1) and build from there. It seems trivial since your list is sorted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$result = [];

foreach($arr as $k=>$v) {
  $path = explode('/', $k);
  // temporary array for one path
  $temp = [];
  // Pointer, used to add a next level 
  $p = &$temp;
  // Save the last part of path
  $last = array_pop($path);
  foreach($path as $s) {
    // Make level upto the last
    $p[$s] = ['children' => []];
    $p = &$p[$s]['children'];
  }
 // Add a value 
 $p[$last] = ['path' => $v];
 $result = array_merge_recursive($result, $temp);
}
print_r($result);
```

[**demo**](https://eval.in/945922)